# General Understanding of IIS and webservice

Tags: web-services, iis

I was just having an Rnd on web services. Thought some of the doubts will get a professional explanation here.

1. When creating a web application why Visual studio generating a random port number? Is it not possible for the user to decide on which port?
2. When publishing a web service in IIS (version 5.1), why always the port number is 80? I know that my default website port is 80, that is why it is taking port as 80. However wondering is it possible to have one website under the default website with port 80 to have a different port number? Or more specifically, is it possible to have another directory like Default website with a different port, so that all the virtual directories under that website will have a different port?
3. If I have a remote server web service how will I access that webservice in another server?
4. What is the significance of Namespace in web service?
5. How can I call another web service from a local web service, in that case what is the use of Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That is the default bevaviour. In Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 you can specify a port you want, like in the following link. This also explains a little what it happens.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109(v=vs.100).aspx
2. Port 80 is the TCP port most used for Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), so it comes default for IIS. You can specify the usage of other ports, as long as they are not used by other application. This goes also for port 80; if it is used by other application (like Skype, very common issue) your web services won't work.
   Microsoft also offers documentation for modifying ports:
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605
3. For accessing a remote web service you must either add a reference to it or invoke it without a reference. There is too much documentation here, depending on the types of web services and how they are developed. More details are needed but this question is too complex so you should do your search.
4. http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/
5. This comes back to question 3 a little. This may deppend on the type of web service.
   Web Services have bindings. XML Web Services have Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute.
   This is just an example of usage http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231/ASP-NET-Web-Service.

But you will need first to read more about web services and IIS.

My responses don't want to respond completely to your questions, because your questions are too general. The complete answer is in the thousand of pages of MSDN documentations (and others) which you should start reading. Also try finding some tutorial to learn by practice.

In the future please post questions about specific problems.